# React testing using snapshots

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, snapshot

I'm wondering, what's your approach while testing React component using Jest snapshots.

Are you testing every component?

How do you determine if you should create a snapshot for component?

Are you testing whole views or only smaller components (view pieces)?

When should one add props to tested components? Should functions always be mocked using jest.fn() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, snapshots are more inclined towards "how" your component look like.

**My Approach**,

Identify the `props` or `state` which can alter the presentation of my component. Then I write snapshots for them.

If you cannot achieve setting the `state` using `props`, you can use `simulate` to make the relevant `state` set and then create a `snapshot`.

And using `jest.fn()` in snapshots, doesnot seems much of an advantage as we mock functions when we actually need to *unit test* whether they were invoked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one more question, do you create different snapshot for component in different state every time?

Comment: if state changes have significant impact on DOM , then why not. :-)